# d3js scatterplot custom icons and animation

Tags: d3.js

I'm just starting with d3js and I wanted to know if it's possible to create a scatterplot with custom icons for the data points similar to this method for [Forced Layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642)?

I don't want to use d3.svg.symbol() as I want to use a custom icon with my company logo to mark each data point.

My final goal is to translate a point (with a custom icon) along a horizontal axis depending on the x value. I've searched high and low on how to do this with d3js but have had no luck.

Comment: This doesn't seem to contain a question. What do you want help with?

Comment: @ckersch That's reworked now so should make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use an icon instead of a symbol, just swap out the path element (that the symbol generator is called on) with an image element.

Given a data set, `D`, with elements like `{src: http.myImageURL, x: 10, y : 20}` it would look something like this:

```
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg');

svg.append('g').selectAll('.myPoint')
  .data(D)
  .enter()
  .append('image')
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d){ return d.src })
  .attr("x", function(d){ return d.x })
  .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y })
  .attr("width", 16)
  .attr("height", 16);
```